# Find Items in one column that are not in another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, conditional-formatting

I have two columns in Excel, and I want to find (preferably highlight) the items that are in column B but not in column A.

What's the quickest way to do this?

Answer (score 144, accepted):

1. Select the list in column A
2. Right-Click and select Name a Range...
3. Enter "ColumnToSearch"
4. Click cell C1
5. Enter this formula: `=MATCH(B1,ColumnToSearch,0)`
6. Drag the formula down for all items in B

If the formula fails to find a match, it will be marked #N/A, otherwise it will be a number.

If you'd like it to be TRUE for match and FALSE for no match, use this formula instead:

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(B1,ColumnToSearch,0))
```

If you'd like to return the **unfound value** and return empty string for found values

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B1,ColumnToSearch,0)),"",B1)
```

Comment: Then...
Put this formula into Conditional Formatting in both lists and and use it to highlight (or whatever) the non-matching cells

Comment: "Name a Range" doesn't appear for me? Tested on Excel 2010 and 2016.

Comment: If, like @KERR and I, you don't have "Name a Range...", just use `A:A` or your range in lieu of `ColumnToSearch` in the formulae.

Comment: If, like me, you don't realize at first where to enter "ColumnToSearch" (step 3), enter it as the name of the named range you are creating.

Comment: "Name a Range" appears as `Define Name...` (Excel 2019)

Comment: Also "Name a Range" only appears if you select a subset of the column, clicking the column header to select the entire column doesn't let you name a range.

Comment: this just seems to tell me if the two cells match, which is not what I want.  I want it to search the entire other column :(

Answer (score 43):

Here's a quick-and-dirty method.

Highlight Column **B** and open **Conditional Formatting**.

Pick **Use a formula to determine which cells to highlight**.

Enter the following formula then set your preferred format.

```
=countif(A:A,B1)=0
```

Comment: I used "=ISODD(COUNTIF(A:A,B1)=0)" to print true for '1' or false for '0'

Comment: For unknown reasons the countif() method doesn't work reliably when specifying a multi-column array (e.g. =countif(B:C,A1)=0) - Excel 2016.

Answer (score 29):

Select the two columns.  Go to Conditional Formatting and select Highlight Cell Rules.  Select Duplicate values.  When you get to the next step you can change it to unique values.  I just did it and it worked for me.

Comment: if you have a value in column B repeated, this will not highlight them

Comment: Surely this is the simplest and most relevant answer? No formulas required.

Comment: Nothing happens when doing this.

Comment: Easily the best answer. Simplest.

Answer (score 18):

Took me forever to figure this out but it's very simple. Assuming data begins in A2 and B2 (for headers) enter this formula in C2:

```
=MATCH(B2,$A$2:$A$287,0)
```

Then click and drag down.

A cell with `#N/A` means that the value directly next to it in column B does not show up anywhere in the entire column A.

Please note that you need to change $A$287 to match your entire search array in Column A. For instance if your data in column A goes down for 1000 entries it should be $A$1000.

Comment: `=MATCH(B2,$A:$A,0)` worked for me.

Comment: what do you mean, 'click and drag down'?  This just makes the cells turn grey.

Answer (score 4):

See my array formula answer to listing A not found in B here:

> =IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$1999,MATCH(0,IFERROR(MATCH($A$2:$A$1999,$B$2:$B$399,0),COUNTIF($C$1:$C1,$A$2:$A$1999)),0)),"")

[Comparing two columns of names and returning missing names](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/comparing-two-columns-of-names-and-returning/ea968fbe-ced3-4037-902a-f135a2baa1f7?page=1&tm=1319205278419#footer)

Comment: This solution is good, but depends on the source columns being sorted alphabetically, or else it retrieves duplicates.

Answer (score 4):

My requirements was not to highlight but to show all values except that are duplicates amongst 2 columns. I took help of @brenton's solution and further improved to show the values so that I can use the data directly:

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(B2,$A$2:$A$2642,0)), A2, "")
```

Copy this in the first cell of the 3rd column and apply the formula through out the column so that it will list all items from column B there are not listed in column A.

Comment: There is an error in the formula above =IF(ISNA(MATCH(B2,$A$2:$A$2642,0)), A2, "") should be =IF(ISNA(MATCH(B2,$A$2:$A$2642,0)), B2, "")

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to those who have shared their answers.  Because of your solutions, I was able to make my way to my own.

In my version of this question, I had two columns to compare -- a full graduating class (Col A) and a subset of that graduating class (Col B).  I wanted to be able to highlight in the full graduating class those students who were members of the subset.

I put the following formula into a third column:

```
=if(A2=LOOKUP(A2,$B$2:$B$91),1100,0)
```

This coded most of my students, though it yielded some errors in the first few rows of data.

Answer (score -3):

in `C1` write `=if(A1=B1 , 0, 1)`. Then in `Conditional formatting`, select `Data bars` or `Color scales`. It's the easiest way.