# Compare lists in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, find

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extract values from a range that are missing from another](https://superuser.com/questions/430854/extract-values-from-a-range-that-are-missing-from-another)

I have two vertical lists. I need to compare the two with each other and get the names that are NOT included in both lists.

```
ListA | ListB
----- | ------
ABC   | ABC
DEF   | DEF
ASD   | GHI
      | ASD
```

Should return:

```
GHI
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to C1 (assuming you're starting at A1 and B1) and drag down for the full length of the list.

```
=CONCATENATE(IF(COUNTIF(A:A,B1), "", B1), IF(COUNTIF(B:B,A1), "", A1))
```