# Mac Excel 2011: find Items in one column that are not in another column

Tags: microsoft-excel-2011, named-ranges

Hi this is a repeat of the question: [Find Items in one column that are not in another column](https://superuser.com/questions/81498/excel-find-items-in-one-column-that-are-not-in-another-column)

> I have two columns in excel, and I want to find (preferably highlight) the items that are in column B, but not in column A.
>
> What's the quickest way to do this?

However, the answer given below to in the above-menitoned thread no longer applies to Mac Excel 2011. E.g. there is no "name-a-range" option available on right click etc.. Therefore I am asking this again.

> Select the list in column A
>   Right-Click and select Name a Range...
>   Enter "ColumnToSearch"
>   Click cell C1
>   Enter this formula: =MATCH(B1,ColumnToSearch,0)
>   Drag the formula down for all items in B
>   If the formula fails to find a match, it will be marked #N/A, otherwise it will be a number.
>
> If you'd like it to be TRUE for match and FALSE for no match, use this formula instead:
>
> > =IF(ISNA(MATCH(B1,ColumnToSearch,0)),FALSE,TRUE)

How should this answer be restated to apply to Mac Excel 2011?

Answer (score 0):

Conditional format of Column B with this formula works for Excel 2007 `=ISNA(MATCH(B1,A:A,0)>0)`.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, Excel for Mac does not have Name Manager or a button on the ribbon for defining a name. The workaround per [this Office help page](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macexcel/how-to-use-name-management-function-in-excel-2011/ab02ab8b-6404-4e6b-b481-e7865b4f5100):

> Go to your system preferences. In the Keyboard Preferences go to the
>   Keyboard tab.
>
> Check the box by Use All F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys.
>
> Now open Excel. One a worksheet, press Command-F3
>
> That may be the dialog you are looking for.